Http post using powershell - Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
When i executed the below command in PowerShell i am getting error. "Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
Code:

$Cred = Get-Credential
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $True }
$Server = 'servername.domain.com'
$Url = "URL"
$Body = @{
Timestamp: "2024-06-14T10:00:00Z",
Value: "888"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Body $body

The above code helps me to write the value back to the web api application using the post method.

Please format your post properly.

You're not using $Cred in your Invoke-RestMethod call, and your $Body value is missing a @ before the opening {

The connection is completing so the credentials are valid.  Error 401 means the user does not have the permission to access the route.  mklement0 is probably correct is the connection is completing with no credentials and the route requires a credential.  The route at the server probably has [Authorize]
